# Is the graph of a real countinuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphic to its domain?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, continuity

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous real funcion and we consider its graph identified by the subset

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\mathcal{G}(f)=\{(x,f(x))\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$

of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ equipped wiht the usual euclidean topology that induced on $\mathcal{G}(f)$ a subspace topology. Well with these condictions we demonstrate that $\mathcal{G}(f)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. So we consider the function

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad h:\mathcal{G}(f)\owns(x,f(x))\rightarrow x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, clearly $h$ is surjective on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then is also inijective because if $h(x,f(x))=h(y,f(y))$ then $x=y$; now to prove the assertion we have to demonstrate of that $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous funcion or that $h$ is open and continuous, but unfortunately I'm not be able to do this so can someone help me?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of examining arbitrary open sets let's use the basis of open rectangles.

To see that $h^{-1}$ is continuous: Take a small open rectangle $R = R_\epsilon\times (a,b)$. The preimage of this rectangle is $R_\epsilon\cap f^{-1}(a,b)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is open, so $h^{-1}(R) = R_\epsilon\cap f^{-1}(a,b)$ is open.

To see that $h$ is continuous: Open rectangles form a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $R\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, then $h^{-1}(R) = R\times (-\infty,\infty)$ with $\mathcal{G}$, hence is open.

Comment: It seems to me that the rectangle $R=R_\epsilon\times(a,b)$ is a open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so if $h^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathcal{G}(f)$ how can $h^{-1}(R)$ be defined? Can you explain better your solution?

Comment: I edited  to be clearer about which "$R$" I mean.

Comment: What did you edit?